# Validate username onchange

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am trying to validate my username on my jsp page. Basically i am trying to see if there is matching domains i want to redirect to some other URL. below is my function.

```
function validateName()
{
    var UserName=document.getElementById('Username').value;

    if (UserName == "@test.com")
    {
        window.location="http://test.test.com";
    }
    else if (UserName == "@test1.com")
    {
        window.location="https://test.test1.com";
    }
    return true
}
```

My form has the onchange event.

```
<p>
Enter the UserName: <input id="Username" name="Username" onchange="validateName()"><br>
</p>
```

How can I validate this right? I don't see above working. Whenever I try to put some "test.com" or "test1.com" I don't see anything happening in the form.

I would appreciate if you could throw some light on this.

Comment: Sorry so the question is. How can i validate this right. I dont see above working. When ever i try to put some test.com or test1.com i dont see anything happening in the form. Appreciate if you could throw some light on this.

Comment: The change event only fires when the input field loses focus …

Comment: Could it be that you're checking in the code equality against "@test1.com" but you're testing "test1.com"? Those strings are not equal to each other, so nothing will happen there.

Comment: I tried exactly like this @test.com to validate whether onchange is triggering. It does not work.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/wtvgx754/)

Comment: @dave. Yes i tried yours . It works great. Not sure it is because i am messing with lots of functions and tags. I tried my entire code there. It is not working still. Please check whether you can access my code.

Comment: Don't use as `var name`, the same string that you use in the object `id`... use for example (in the function): `var username_to_check = UserName.value;`

Comment: I see this issue when i have my validate session function block in the jsp. Here is my another function which i validate window.onload = function validateSession()
{
 } basically i do the cookie validation here in the validatesession

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup="validateName()"` instead of `onchange="validateName()"`

Comment: I tried onkeyup. That does not work as well. If i had a alert message in the function. I can see it is working in onchange event . But other than that nothing i see is happening.  I tried to remove the alert and tried to print the Username in System.out. I don't see nothing coming up in console as well.

Comment: Why dont you just add the console.log to check whether if is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Never use as `var name`, the same string previously used as `object id`...

The `object ID` & `var name` you're going to use must be different <sup>(case insensitive)</sup>.

```
// This:
var UserName = document.getElementById('Username').value;
     \            \
      \_ Var Name  \
                    \_ Object Property

// is the same as:
var UserName = Username.value;
     \            \
      \_ Var Name  \
                    \_ Object Property
```

With this, <sup>(remember, case insensitive)</sup> your `var name` has conflicts with your `object ID`, so in your function, you're actually comparing:

```
if ( username == username.value ) {...}
      \            \
       \_ Object    \
                     \_ Object Property
// will never be true
```

***So, in brief...

change that var name in your function with something else.***

```js
function validateName()
{
    var UserNameToCheck = document.getElementById('Username').value;

    if (UserNameToCheck == "@test.com")
    {
        alert("http://test.test.com");
        //window.location="http://test.test.com";
    }
    else if (UserNameToCheck == "@test1.com")
    {
        alert("http://test.test1.com");
        //window.location="https://test.test1.com";
    }
    return true
}
```

```html
<p>
Enter the UserName: <input id="Username" name="Username" onchange="validateName()"><br>
</p>
```

***... or don't use it at all and check's directly...***

```
function validateName()
{
    if ( Username.value == "@test.com" ) {...}
}
```

Comment: I found the issue. Somehow the issue is with the function name. It is creating some conflict with other. So i changed the function name. Now it is working fine. One quick question. The username is generally like aish@test.com How can i validate the domain only. Basically i want to check the domain name and redirect instead of username.

Comment: Is `UserName` the user `email` then?.. In that case, you can use the *split function* like: `var host= UserName.split("@");` and access with: `host[1]` in the validation. (host[0] is the string before at, host[1] everything after, an so on...)

Comment: I tried this. Does not work.function domainCheck()
{
 //alert("test");
   
   var uname = Username.split("@");
   System.out.println(host[1]);
    if (uname[1]  == "test.com")
    {
        
     window.location="https://test.test.com
     
        
        
    }else if (uname[1]  == "test1.com")
    {
    
     window.location="http://test.test1.com"}
    return true;
    
}

Comment: basically i noticed when ever i defined a var and then doing the above validation it is not working. But i see this is working fine.                       function domainCheck()
{
 
  // var host = Username.split("@");
  // System.out.println(host[1]);
    if (Username.value  == "test.com")
    {
        
     window.location="https://test.test.com";
     
        
        
    }else if (Username.value  == "test1.com")
    {
    
     window.location="https://test.test1.com";
    }
    return true;
    
}

Comment: Thanks Finally it worked.  I did something wrong. Your suggestion worked great.

Comment: I'm glad you finally solved. good luck with your project. ;-)